# SlimerJs PDF Render to file

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfrenderer, slimerjs

I am looking at SlimerJs (v0.9.6) as an option for rendering PDFs. I have marked up the HTML that the PDF should be rendered from and I run this command to render it out:

```
slimerjs renderPdf.js
```

In my `renderPdf.js` file I have defined:

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();
webpage
  .open('page.html') // loads a page
  .then(function() {
    webpage.viewportSize = { width: 1240, height: 1754 };
    webpage.render('page.pdf', { 
                      format:'pdf',
                      onlyViewport:true 
                    });
    slimer.exit();
  });
```

I see a window open with the HTML page rendered exactly as expected but it doesn't render to the defined file, `page.pdf`. Is there something I am missing to get it to render out to a file? Or perhaps there's a known issue around this? Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Same here, it does render png files though. I'm using the phantom.js rasterize script for comparison.

Comment: use the slimer 0.10pre release. 0.9.6 doesn't have pdf rendering included yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [@three](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492969/three)'s comment suggestion I used the 0.10pre release version and was able to get a PDF. Mind you at the time of posting this release is not super stable so might want to wait for the final release build.

Answer (score 2):

Please note in order to print the webpage to pdf slimer js requires cups pdf. Install the cups pdf with this command then it will render the page to a local file. And higher version than 0.9.6 is needed (0.10.*).

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```